# Make a Custom Friendly URL for blog in PHP using .htaccess Not Working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My url is like this: `http://example.com/blog/blog.php?id=38`
and in `blog.php` I am using `$_GET` and showing the title and all descriptions about the blog.

However, I want to make it something like this: `http://example.com/blog/this-can-be-blog-title`

I've tried this `.htaccess` to make it at least look like this : `http://example.com/blog/blog/id/38/`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule blog/id/(.*)/ blog.php?id=$1
RewriteRule blog/id/(.*) blog.php?id=$1
```

But even this doesn't work.There is no change in the url. What am I missing ?

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no change in the URL"? Note that internal rewriting does not somehow magically change the URLs some application like a CMS hands out. Rewriting only handles _incoming requests_ to some URL.

Comment: What should I do then ?

Comment: I'm not using any CMS

Comment: Well, where are the URL's defined that your client requests? That is where you have to change things. _Then_, if those URLs are requested by whatever client, _then_ rewriting comes into play to map those "virtual" URLs back onto existing objects internally.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .htaccess

```
   RewriteEngine on  
   RewriteBase /
 # mod_rewrite ignore rules if a matching file or directory exists
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 
   RewriteRule .* - [L]


 # generate url
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$  blog/blog.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

You will need to get the proper page from your database that has "this-can-be-blog-title" slug via URL GET parameter and no more query based on id.

If you just want to pass id as GET parameter use this:

```
   RewriteEngine on  
   RewriteBase /
 # mod_rewrite ignore rules if a matching file or directory exists
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 
   RewriteRule .* - [L]


 # generate url
   RewriteRule ^blog/id/(.*)$  blog/blog.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ok. for a min forget about custom lug title. How can I get just http://example.com/blog/123

Comment: Please explain the meaning of ^(.*)$ and -[L]

Comment: and these RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]

Comment: L flag meas that leave the script if it matches the regex

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 
   RewriteRule .* - [L]
let you access real files and folders out of URL maspping

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+blog/blog\.php\?id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/id/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^blog/id/(\d+)/?$ blog/blog.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: My code with `http://example.com/blog/id/38/` not `http://example.com/blog/blog/id/38/`(2x blog)